# Press a button and have that same button appear on the same page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I am building a horoscope app where each sign is a button.

When you click the button that has your sign a popup view controller will appear on the screen with your horoscope.

I built out the app for one sign/horoscope

[image]

Again every image and corresponding sign title is a button.

So the fish symbol and the word "Pisces" is one button.

I want to add to my app where you can click any horoscope and it will give you the corresponding information.

I built my app in the interface builder first and then added the code so that might be where the gaps in my knowledge come from.

**Question: I am wondering if there is a way to capture the image that I set [image]
to make each button and have it displayed on the PopUp screen instead of having the image for Pisces show up each time.

This is my view controller class which has the code for the main three pages

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Zodiac
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var buttonImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func ShowCharacteristicsPopup(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopChar") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    //let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal)!
    //print(buttonTitle)
    //buttonImage = sender.currentImage!
    //print(buttonImage)
}

@IBAction func ShowDailyPopup(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopDay") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

@IBAction func ShowYearlyPopup(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopYear") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

}

This is my popup view controller class which has the code for the popup view controllers (the third row of screens if you look at the interface builder map)

```
//  PopUpViewController.swift
//  Zodiac
import UIKit
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {
//@IBOutlet weak var vc: ViewController!
@IBOutlet weak var popUpButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showAnimate()
    //print(vc.buttonImage)
    //popUpButton.setImage(vc.buttonImage, for: .normal)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func ClosePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    removeAnimate()
}

func showAnimate() {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3,y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0,y: 1.0)
    });
}

func removeAnimate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3,y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished : Bool) in
        if (finished) {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
}
```

}

In the ShowCharacteristicsPopup function in the ViewController I attempted to get the sender.currentImage, then access it in the popupviewcontroller but this crashed my program.

Also if anyone has any structure tips I am all ears

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but what you have to do is:

1. Get the UIImage in the "ShowCharacteristicsPopup"
2. Set the UIImage for the button of the PopUpViewController in the "ShowCharacteristicsPopup" function as well

Try something like:

```
popOverVC.popUpButton.setImage(sender.currentImage!, for: .normal)
```

This line of code goes before the "    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
" one.

Alternatively you can move this line

```
var buttonImage: UIImage?
```

To INSIDE the PopUpViewController, then on the "ShowCharacteristicsPopup" set the buttonImage of the popOverVC, then your code should work changing the "vc." to "self."